# How would I be able to return more than one object based on user input amount

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

Let's say `PackInput` is an array input.

What I'd like to do's `return` a dynamic amount of objects depending on how large the input array `PackInput` is.

For example: if `PackInput` is `[4,5,6]`, then I'd like three objects returned for each  `ItemID`.

For example: `return {... ItemID: 4 ...}`,  `return {... ItemID: 5 ...}`, `return {... ItemID: 6 ...}`.

My current code below is only grabbing the first item of the array instead of all of them and I'm not sure why.  I've turned my wheels on this for so long and now I've hit a wall.  What am I doing wrong?

```
for(let i = 0; i < PackInput.length; i++) {      
        return {
            TimestampUTC: Date.now(),
            Payload: {
                ItemID : PackInput[i]
            }
        }
}
```

Updated:

```
let array = PackInput.map((items) => ({
        TimestampUTC: Date.now(),
        Payload: {
            ItemID : items
        }
   })
);

let objects = array.reduce(function(target, key, index) {
    target[index] = key;
    return target;
}) 

return objects;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to achieve what you want

```
return PackInput.map((element) => ({
  TimestampUTC: Date.now(),
  Payload: {
    ItemID : element
  }
}))
```

A return statement ends the execution of a function, and returns control to the calling function/upper scope.

**Update on object:**

```
const object = PackInput.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index) {
    return {
      ...previousValue,
      [index]: currentValue
    }
}, {})
```

You need to provide an empty object as 2nd argument for the reduce function.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This is good but I have another question.  I'd like to return individual objects instead of an array.  Instead of returning `PackInput`, I've assigned it a variable called `input` and tried to convert to an object via `const obj = Object.fromEntries(input);` and returned the `obj` value but it didn't work.  Any suggestions on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Yes, i like to use the reduce method to convert an array to object, for example
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const result = array1.reduce(
  (previousValue, currentValue, index) => ({...previousValue, ['id_'+index]: currentValue}),
  {}
);

the brackets inside the object are used for dynamic object keys

Comment: I tried your way but it didn't work.  However, if you check my updated original post's code - the way I did it, it's still only grabbing the first item of the array instead of all of them.  What did I do wrong here?

Comment: I've updated my response, you need to provide { } as an initial value for the reduce function(2nd argument)

Comment: I already tried that.  If I provide the `{}` then no items gets grabbed.  If I don't provide the `{}`, then only the first item gets grabbed instead of all of them.

Comment: You can check this working example here, check the console on bottom right for the output, https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-snowflake-6s0wkj?file=/src/index.js

Comment: I think I need to use the spread operator somewhere (`...`)

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array/object. The problem is that you can call `return` only once in a function and as soon as a function reaches `return` it would be **returned** to the caller scope. You can use the loop to create the array/object and then return the final value:

```
let array = [];
for(let i = 0; i < PackInput.length; i++) {      
        array.push({
            TimestampUTC: Date.now(),
            Payload: {
                ItemID : PackInput[i]
            }
        });
} 

return array;
```